# Blender Error - Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones

Tags: анимация, blender

Я хочу сделать анимацию своего персонажа.

Делаю костную структуру, как [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp_SqjB0468).

Блендер выдаёт ошибку.

[image]

[image]

(*Я думаю ошибка связана с плечами*).

Что не так, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это довольно частая ошибка, возникающая из-за пересекающихся мешей. Что можно попробовать сделать:

1. Части которые пересекаются отделить и назначить арматуру по отдельности, затем обратно все соединить.
2. Убрать места пересечения (временно)
3. Проверить нет ли сдублированых мешей (<kbd>w</kbd>->remove doubles)

В вашем случае - третье